# Could not get the second integer from a string

Tags: c, string

I am learning sscanf in C at the moment, I wrote this piece of code:

```
char str[100] ="123asdrZXC456";
char lowercase[100];
char uppercase[100];
int num1;
int num2;
sscanf(str,"%d %[^a-z] %[^A-Z] %d", &num1,lowercase, uppercase,  &num2);
printf("The number is: %d.\n", num1);
printf("The number is: %d.\n", num2);
return 0;
```

I want to obtain the second integer "456" from the given string. But here is the output:

```
The number is: 123.
The number is: 0.
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Where does my code go wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You are using `%[^a-z]` which means that you want to read characters that are neither `'a'`, nor `'b'`, nor `'c'`, etc. The circumflex `^` should be use to **exclude** the following characters from the match. Remove the `^`:

```
sscanf(str,"%d %[a-z] %[A-Z] %d", &num1,lowercase, uppercase,  &num2);
```

then it will print

```
The number is: 123.
The number is: 456.
```

> *man scanf*
>
> **Conversions**
>
> ...
>
> `[`: Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of
>   accepted characters; [...] **The set excludes those characters if the
>   first character after the open bracket is a circumflex (`^`).** [...]

Comment: `sscanf(str,"%d %[a-z] %[A-Z] %d", &num1,lowercase, uppercase,  &num2);` should be `sscanf(str,"%d%[a-z]%[A-Z]%d", &num1,lowercase, uppercase,  &num2);` since input string do not have whitespace.

Comment: @RajmaniArya no, the spaces are fine, since they match *any amount  of  white space, including none* (quote from the man page). See https://ideone.com/JzhPgf

Comment: Note that you could also have 10 white spaces between the conversion specifiers and this would still work. A space in `scanf` is special, because they match any number of white spaces.